# Is there a way to show the x-axis reference line till a particular y-axis value in recharts?

Tags: reactjs, recharts

I was using recharts to plot graphs in my react app. I wanted to achieve something like the picture below shows:

[image]

The only problem is that, I want the reference line to end at the point where green and blue lines in the picture, intersect. I just can't figure out how to stop the x-axis reference line to stop over-shooting about a certain y-axis value. Also, if there is a possibility to achieve the same with some other reacharts component, please do let me know.